# Create Azure EventHub via CLI with Capture

Tags: azure-cli, azure-eventhub

Scenario: I am putting together a repeatable script that creates, among other things, an Azure EventHub.  My code looks like:

```
az eventhubs eventhub create \
    --name [name] \
    --namespace-name [namespace] \
    --resource-group [group] \
    --status Active \
    --enable-capture true \
    --archive-name-format "{Namespace}/{EventHub}/{Year}/{Month}/{Day}/{Hour}/{Minute}/{Second}/{PartitionId}" \
    --storage-account [account] \
    --blob-container [blob] \
    --capture-interval 300 \
    --partition-count 10 \
    --skip-empty-archives true
```

If I run the code as written, I get a "Required property 'name' not found in JSON. Path 'properties.captureDescription.destination', line 1, position 527."

However, if I remove the --enable-capture true parameter, the EventHub is created, albeit with Capture not enabled.  If I enable Capture, none of the capture-related parameters other than the interval are set.

Is there a typo in there that I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 1):

Try providing the --destination-name.

[image]

```html
az eventhubs eventhub create --name
                             --namespace-name
                             --resource-group
                             [--archive-name-format]
                             [--blob-container]
                             [--capture-interval]
                             [--capture-size-limit]
                             [--destination-name]
                             [--enable-capture {false, true}]
                             [--message-retention]
                             [--partition-count]
                             [--skip-empty-archives {false, true}]
                             [--status {Active, Disabled, SendDisabled}]
                             [--storage-account]
```

Comment: Success!  Another +1 for StackOverflow (and a -1 to Microsoft documentation that doesn't mention you need that parameter if you enable capture)